# Selenium cannot find element in page

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get selenium to press the download button on this page.

[Link](https://modsbase.com/yjdfcs34gxix/1863514508_BetterCheats.zip.html)

I've been trying to use

```
mod = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#method_free').click()
```

but I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need basically explicit waits, cause the id in HTML DOM is unique.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://modsbase.com/yjdfcs34gxix/1863514508_BetterCheats.zip.html")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "method_free"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Note that once you `click` on the `download` a `new tab` is opening up, to interact with the web element in that `new window`, you'd need to switch.

```
all_handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])
```

and then you can interact with new windows item.

Comment: That did it, Thank you.